# How can I hide email templates that are not available to use in the folders under "My Templates"

Tags: email-template, setup

Our call center agents can see the email template folders that they have access to under Setup > Email > My Templates. They see email templates that are not flagged as "Available to Use", too, and some of them do copy texts from them, which they should not do.

Is it possible to hide the email templates that are not available to use?

The agents should still be able to select templates when sending emails from cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you can do is to move those templates to folders they don't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,But you need to create folders because Email templates are stored in folders, So,we can give different security access to the folders.When you create a new folder, you can select either Public Read Only or Public Read/Write, and more over  drill down to sharing settings:

You can select option

This folder is hidden from all users

For reference:[Create & edit folders](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_and_editing_folders.htm)